# How can I change the size of a StackPane that is inside of a VBox, and allow the VBox to stretch to that size?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I have a StackPane with nodes that resize themselves based on the current size of the StackPane. I have this StackPane placed inside of a VBox, which is the root of the scene. The StackPane grows and shrinks based on the size of the scene (ie grows and shrinks when the user resizes the window). All of this functionality works, but when the program is run, the window created by the program is very small, and the user has to resize it to be larger to see the elements within.

I have tried setting the prefWidth and prefHeight of the StackPane, but the VBox doesn't seem to resize itself based on the StackPane's prefWidth and prefHeight. I also considered setting the prefWidth and prefHeight of the VBox, which works, but isn't ideal, since I wind up having to determine the size of all of the nodes rather than having them calculate their own sizes.

The simple equivalent of what I have:

```
VBox root = new VBox();
MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(250, 50);
StackPane sp = new StackPane();

//sp.setPrefSize(300, 300);

root.getChildren().addAll(menu, rect, sp);

Scene scene = new Scene(root);

sp.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
sp.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().subtract(menu.heightProperty().subtract(rect.heightProperty()));

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

What's the smart way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround solution that isn't ideal, but works. I created a transparent rectangle and placed it at the back of the StackPane, and the VBox, scene, and stage resized to the size of the rectangle.